# interpolation and projection on geo-spatial data

Tags: gps, interpolation, projection

everyone

recently I am trying to solve the location error generated by GPS, so I came up with an idea of projecting the GPS points to the nearest road, as shown bellow [1]. But I know that indeed earth is not a flat plane and general projection method is not adaptive to this problem. What should I do to deal with the projection problem that exists on sphere to get a better precision?

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKaWP.jpg

Similarly, when it comes to interpolation between two points, same problem emerged. I did once assume two points were closed so I could ignore the flatness
effect, but failed if their distance was long enough. Regular interpolation method won't give me a better-precision result.

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uRm.jpg

Comment: If you where to use a Geo-Cording tool, such as [`Nominatim`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), would that fix your problem?

Comment: Are you talking about [Crosstrack Error](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#XTE)?